# How to position css post items properly when using grid display

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can i make the `#post-date` , `#post-author-name` elements appear like how they do in this image below: [image]

instead of this messed up page in the pic below: [image]

the full code is slightly big so i've pasted it on the codepen snippet below (it wont show the post like that bcs it uses the reddit api to show posts from a subreddit)
https://codepen.io/salahmak/pen/RwwOjMV

or:

```js
// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// No Node.js APIs are available in this process because
// `nodeIntegration` is turned off. Use `preload.js` to
// selectively enable features needed in the rendering
// process.


const remote = require('electron').remote;

(function () {
    function init() {
        document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.minimize();
        });
        document.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            if (!window.isMaximized()) {
                window.maximize();
            } else {
                window.unmaximize();
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.close();
        });
    };
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
            init();
        }
    };
})();

MAIN();
async function MAIN() {
    const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
    const userAgent = 'electron.js:DZGC APP:v0.0.1 (by /u/Mr_DJA for /r/Dz_Gamers_Community)';
    const clientId = 'Sl36RL-uj9P3CA';
    const Store = require('electron-store');
    const store = new Store();
    //const Keyv = require('keyv');
    //const DB = new Keyv('sqlite://data.sqlite');
    //DB.on('error', err => console.error('(DB) Keyv connection error:', err));

    const GetNewRefreshToken = async function (callback) {
        const baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/';
        const request = require('request-promise').defaults({
            json: true,
            baseUrl
        });
        const port = 65010;
        const expected_redirect_uri = `http://localhost:${port}/authorize_callback`;
        const scope = 'account creddits edit flair history identity livemanage modconfig modcontributors modflair modlog modmail modothers modposts modself modtraffic modwiki mysubreddits privatemessages read report save structuredstyles submit subscribe vote wikiedit wikiread';
        const state = require('crypto').randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
        const authenticationUrl = `${baseUrl}authorize?${require('querystring').stringify({ client_id: clientId, response_type: 'code', state, redirect_uri: expected_redirect_uri, duration: 'permanent', scope: scope, })}` //refreshToken      
        document.getElementById("login-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            require('open')(authenticationUrl);
        });
        var server = require('http').createServer((req) => {
            const query = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;
            console.log('--------------------query--------------------');
            console.log(query);
            console.log('---------------------------------------------');
            if (query.state !== state) {
                console.error(401);
                server.close();
                callback('Error: 401');
            } else if (query.code) {
                request.post({
                    uri: 'access_token',
                    auth: {
                        user: clientId,
                        pass: ''
                    },
                    form: {
                        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                        code: query.code,
                        redirect_uri: expected_redirect_uri
                    },
                }).then(token_info => {
                    console.log('-----------------token_info-----------------');
                    console.log(token_info);
                    console.log('--------------------------------------------');
                    //DB.set("refresh_token", token_info["refresh_token"]);
                    store.set('refresh_token', token_info["refresh_token"]);
                    server.close();
                    callback(token_info["refresh_token"]);
                }).catch(err => console.error(err));
            } else if (query.error === 'access_denied') {
                server.close();
                callback('Error: access_denied');
            } else {
                console.error({
                    statusCode: 400,
                    statusMessage: 'Failed to parse response from reddit'
                })
                server.close();
                callback('Error: 400');
            }
        }).listen(port);
    }

    const GetRefreshToken = async function (callback) {
        const RefreshToken = await store.get('refresh_token');
        console.log('RT: ' + RefreshToken);
        callback(RefreshToken);
    }

    const Login = async function (refreshToken, callback) {
        const r = new snoowrap({
            userAgent: userAgent,
            clientId: clientId,
            clientSecret: '',
            refreshToken: refreshToken || '',
        });
        const test = await r.getMe().name.catch(console.error);
        if (test) {
            callback(r);
        }
        if (!test) {
            GetNewRefreshToken(newRefreshToken => {
                const r1 = new snoowrap({
                    userAgent: userAgent,
                    clientId: clientId,
                    clientSecret: '',
                    refreshToken: newRefreshToken,
                });
                callback(r1);
            });
        }
    }

    GetRefreshToken(async refreshToken => {
        Login(refreshToken, async (r) => {

            const DZGC = r.getSubreddit('Dz_Gamers_Community');
            const userAvatar = await r.getMe().icon_img.catch(console.error);
            const userName = await r.getMe().name.catch(console.error);
            const subredditIcon = await DZGC.community_icon.catch(console.error);
            //const subredditCover = await r.getMe().icon_img.catch(console.error);

            DZGC.subscribe();
            document.getElementById("profile-picture").style.backgroundImage = `url(${userAvatar})`;
            document.getElementById("user-name").innerHTML = userName;

            document.getElementById("subreddit-icon").style.backgroundImage = `url(${subredditIcon})`;

            const elem1 = document.getElementById("login");
            elem1.parentNode.removeChild(elem1);

            const posts = await r.getSubreddit('Dz_Gamers_Community').getNew({ 'limit': 1000 });
            //const posts = await r.getSubreddit('gaming').getHot({ 'limit': 1000 });

            for (let post in posts) {
                if (posts.hasOwnProperty(post) && !isNaN(post)) {
                    console.log(posts[post]);
                    //console.log(`${post} : ${posts[post].title} : ${posts[post].selftext}`)
                    console.log(posts[post].created_utc * 1000)
                    console.log(new Date(posts[post].created_utc * 1000))
                    console.log(timeSince(new Date(posts[post].created_utc * 1000)))
                    const postsContainer = document.getElementById("posts");

                    let postBlock = document.createElement("ul");
                    postBlock.innerHTML = `
                    <li id="post-bar">
                        <div id="post-author-icon" style="background-image: url('${await posts[post].author.icon_img}');"></div>
                        <div id="post-author-name">${posts[post].author.name}</div>
                        <div id="post-date">${timeSince(new Date(posts[post].created_utc * 1000))}</div>
                        <div id="post-stats">
                            <div id="post-comments-stats"></div>
                            <div id="post-score-stats"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="post-save-btn"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="post-title">${posts[post].title}</li>
                    <li id="post-content">${posts[post].selftext_html}</li>
                    <li id="post-attachment">
                        <img src="${await posts[post].url}"></img>
                    </li>
                    `;

                    postBlock.setAttribute("id", posts[post].name);
                    postBlock.classList.add("post-block");
                    postsContainer.appendChild(postBlock);

                }
            }

        });
    });
}

function timeSince(timeStamp) {
    var now = new Date(),
      secondsPast = (now.getTime() - timeStamp.getTime()) / 1000;
    if(secondsPast < 60){
      return parseInt(secondsPast) + 's';
    }
    if(secondsPast < 3600){
      return parseInt(secondsPast/60) + 'm';
    }
    if(secondsPast <= 86400){
      return parseInt(secondsPast/3600) + 'h';
    }
    if(secondsPast > 86400){
        day = timeStamp.getDate();
        month = timeStamp.toDateString().match(/ [a-zA-Z]*/)[0].replace(" ","");
        year = timeStamp.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() ? "" :  " "+timeStamp.getFullYear();
        return day + " " + month + year;
    }
}
```

```css
/*/////////////////////////////////
////////////WINDOW PART////////////
/////////////////////////////////*/

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#window {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border: 3px solid #3554ba;
 position: absolute;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#title-bar {
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #101d55;
 user-select: none;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

#icon {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-image: url('./assets/titlebar/icon.png');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#title {
 font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 left: 22px;
}

#buttons {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}

#close-btn {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: none;
 font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets Local";
 font-size: 8px;
 outline: none;
}

#max-btn {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: none;
 font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets Local";
 font-size: 8px;
 outline: none;
}

#min-btn {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: none;
 font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets Local";
 font-size: 8px;
 outline: none;
}

#close-btn:hover {
 background-color: #ff2c39;
}

#max-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2cf9ff;
}

#min-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2cf9ff;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets Local";
 src: url("./assets/fonts/SegMDL2.ttf");
}




.post-block {
 background: powderblue;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 height: fit-content;
 width: 700px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}


#post-bar {
 height: 60px;
 background: #878787;
}

#post-author-icon {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 position: relative;
 top: 9px;
 left: 15px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border: 1px solid #2cf9ff;
}

#post-author-name {
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 line-height: 22px;
}

#post-date {
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 line-height: 12px;
 font-size: 10px;
}


#post-title {
 background: rgb(142, 155, 168);
 color: white;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}

#post-content {
 background: #878787;
 unicode-bidi: plaintext;
 text-align: -webkit-auto;
}

#post-content * {
 background: #878787;
 unicode-bidi: plaintext;
 text-align: -webkit-auto;
 margin: 0;
}

#post-attachment {
 background: #e3e3e4;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#post-attachment * {
 width: 700px;
}



/*/////////////////////////////////
/////////////LOGIN PART////////////
/////////////////////////////////*/

#login {
    position: fixed;
    top: 23px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
 bottom: 3px;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 z-index: 1;
}

#login * {
 z-index: 1;
}

#login-logo {
 position: relative;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 border: 3px solid #2cf9ff;
 top: 10%;
 margin: auto;
 background-image: url('./assets/images/logo.png');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#login-btn {
 position: relative;
 border: 3px solid #2cf9ff;
 top: 120%;
 transform: translate(50%, 0%);
} 








  /* width */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 5px;
  }
  
  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black; 
 border-radius: 10px;
  }
   
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: white; 
 border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  
  .grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 300px 5% auto 5%;
 grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
 background-image: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/Discord-discordapp-discord-background-1278375.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
  }
  
 #menu {
 display: grid;
 background-color: #36393f;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 2;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 2 end;
 grid-template-rows: auto 65px;
  }
  
   #posts-wrapper {
 display: grid;
 background-color: gray;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
 grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
 grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
  
  #posts {
 background-color: #36393f;
 grid-row-start: 2;
 grid-row-end: 3;
  }

  #posts > .creator-container {
 width: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 70px;
 background-color: #292b2f;
  }
  
  .creator-container > .post-type {
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 2;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  .post-type > .text-post {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border: none;
  }
  
  .text-post:focus {
 outline: 1px solid #fff;
 outline-offset: -1px;
  }
  
  
  
  .post-type > .media-post {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 border-left: 1px solid grey;
 border-right: none;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: none;
  }
  
  
  .post-title > .title-text {
 width: 96%;
 grid-row-start: 2;
 grid-row-end: 3;
 padding: 8px 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .title-text:focus {
 border: 1px solid white;
 outline: none !important;
  }
  
  .post-content > .post-data {
 width: 96%;
 height: 180px;
 grid-row-start: 3;
 grid-row-end: 4;
 padding: 8px 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .post-data:focus {
 border: 1px solid white;
 outline: none !important;
  }
  
  .post-footer {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100px 100px auto 100px;
 grid-gap: 25px;
 grid-row-start: 4;
 grid-row-end: 5;
  }
  
  .post-footer > .spoiler {
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 font-size: 19px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 padding: 2px 0px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-left: 25px;
  }
  
  .post-footer > .nsfw {
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 font-size: 19px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 padding: 2px 0px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-left: 25px;
  }
  
  .post-footer > .post {
 background-color: #7289da;
 grid-column-start: 4;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 font-size: 19px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 padding: 2px 0px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 border-radius: 2px;
  }
  
  .menu-footer {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 5px 42px 100px auto 64px 5px;
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border-top: #2cf9ff 1px solid;
  }
  
  #profile-picture {
 height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #2cf9ff;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  
   #user-name {
 font-size: 14px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: sans-serif;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 grid-column-start: 3;
  }
  
  .menu-scroll {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 160px;
  }
  
  .menu-scroll>.cover {
 background-color: #292b2f;
 border-bottom: #2cf9ff 1px solid;
  }
  
  #subreddit-bar {
   height: 60px;
   width: 300px;
   top: 100px;
   position: absolute;
  }
  
  #subreddit-icon {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 9px;
   left: 15px;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: 1px solid #2cf9ff;
  }
  
  #subreddit-name {
 font-size: 17px;
   position: absolute;
   height: 22px;
   bottom: 19px;
   left: 65px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   line-height: 22px;
  }
  
  #create-post-btn {
 display: block;
 background-color: #7289da;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 grid-column-start: 5;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
  }
  
  .menu-scroll>.menu-list {
  
 overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .list-item {
 background-color: tomato;
 padding: 5px 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 160px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DZGC APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="window">
        <div id="title-bar">
            <div id="icon"></div>
            <div id="title">Dz Gamers Community App</div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <!--
                --><button id="min-btn">&#xE921;</button>
                <!--
                --><button id="max-btn">&#xE922;</button>
                <!--
                --><button id="close-btn">&#xE8BB;</button>
                <!--
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   

    <div class="grid" id="container">
            <div class="grid-item" id="menu">
       
                            <div class="menu-scroll">
                                <div class="cover">
                                        <div id="subreddit-bar">
                                                <div id="subreddit-icon"></div>
                                                <div id="subreddit-name">Dz Gamers Community</div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="menu-list">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                
                            <div class="menu-footer">
                
                                    <div id="profile-picture"></div>
                                    <div id="user-name">USER NAME</div>
                                    <button id="create-post-btn">+</button>
                
                            </div>
                
                       </div>

   <div class="grid" id="posts-wrapper">
        <div id="posts">
            
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
       
    

    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would recommend is `changing post-bar`, `post-author-icon`, `post-author-name`, and `post-date` to `class` instead of `id` since you may be showing multiple posts on a page (`id` should only be used once).

Add the following css to `post-bar`:

```
.post-bar {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
}
```

Then if you wrap the `post-author-name` and `post-date` div they will display as block on top of each other next to your `post-author-icon` div:

```
<div class="post-bar">
    <div class="post-author-icon"></div>
    <div class="post-info">
        <div class="post-author-name">Name</div>
        <div class="post-date">Date</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT

also, something that might make your life easier is instead of relative position:

```
.post-author-icon{
    position: relative; 
    top: 9px;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Try using margins instead:

```
.post-author-icon{
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```